# Start learning C# without knowing C?

Tags: c#, c

Is it advisable to directly jump onto C# with knowing just a mere bit of C (just some basics) or even may be without knowing C ?

Comment: It's probably better that you don't know c. The idioms are very different. Some people write c# while carrying over a bunch of c idioms, and their code is painful to read.

Comment: are you entirely new to .NET?  Just curious

Comment: yup entirely new to .net .. i'm a student actually ( into electronics and love doing stuff with embedded systems ( microcontrollers) ).... People in my family are just way too tilted towards .net,java and stuff and that makes my ming boggle and adds up curiosity with the stuff they work out using languages .. and my mind says "even u try it out - becoz nothings impossible "

Comment: C# and C are so radically different in terms of programming paradigms that you are likely much better off learning C# if that's your current goal.

Comment: if you are into embedded, its better to learn C first.
As learning C after C# can be a little intimidating

Comment: You may be interested in the .NET Micro Framework. Scott Hanselman interviews Colin Miller about it and has a couple demo's on this video http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Glucose/Hanselminutes-on-9-The-NET-Micro-Framework-with-Colin-Miller/

Comment: If you are gonna do embedded stuff I would say C any time. Almost all micro controllers can be programmed in C. I can tell you that it's a different case with C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is to learn your first language, and you aren't going to become a serious programmer, by all means learn the language you're going to use.

If you are going to become a serious programmer, you really should get proficient in C sometime.  I don't know which way would be harder, starting with C# or starting with C.  C will be challenging no matter when you approach it.

If you already know some languages, just not C or C#, go for C# now and pick up C later.

The key is that C is a simpler language, but getting significant things done in it requires more complicated structures.  Some things you can easily do in C# will be difficult in C, although C is the more widespread and versatile language.

Comment: > If you are going to become a serious programmer, you really should get proficient in C sometime.<br/>
I disagree. If your goal is to be a serious C# developer and you don't already know C, focus on C#. Instead of spending time becoming proficient in C, broaden your skills in the .Net space. Start with a solid understanding of OO in practice. Learn design patterns, architecture. In your spare time, develop an understanding of how things work at a low level -- what's really going on within the code and on the machine. These steps will better deliver the goal of becoming a proficient developer.

Comment: Why do you believe that "serious programmers" should learn C? At the risk of sounding short sighted, I currently develop solely in .NET (may not always be that way), but my personal development focus's on the .NET framework in general, better use of patterns and best practices and I'd like to learn a functional language (F# is a candidate). At this moment I really do not see why I should learn a language that I don't see myself using. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @Mark:  C is part of developing an understanding of how things work at a low level, which you seem to agree with me is a good thing.  @Nathan:  Learning different languages will widen your range of thinking, and make you a better developer.

Comment: Serious programmers of embedded systems, as Dharavk may wish to be, should definitely learn C.  Most of the time, your only choices on an embedded system are C, ASM, or a weird esoteric language that you probably hadn't even heard of until you tried to work with a particular embedded system.  A small number of more advanced embedded systems support other languages (e.g. Java VMs), but that's more the exception than the rule.

Comment: C is a good language to learn because to understand why it is the way it is requires you to become familiar with how a computer really works.

Comment: I recently completed a course in c++ going from basic --> actionscript --> c# -- c++. I knew all about bytes bits etc from junior school, but once I finally saw it all in action properly in c, my understanding of performance in all the other languages suddenly made so much more sense.

Answer (score 38):

C# and C are very different, they share syntax but the style of programming is quite different. It wouldn't hurt learning C but if your target is C# then start with that.

Learning C will teach you more about how a computer works and give you a low level understanding. C# is a high level language with a lower learning curve to get a graphical interface.

Joel and Jeff frequently discuss the value of learning C, [stackoverflow podcast #2](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-2/) is one example

Comment: The audio on that podcast is really messed up.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, the C programming language is not a prerequisite for learning C#.  Knowing some C will definitely help you get up to speed on C# syntax but beyond that there are few similiarities.

Answer (score 14):

Sure.  C# borrows semantic conventions from C but there's certainly no requirement to learn it.

In fact, you'll skip the phase where you're trying to use C# as though it were C.

Answer (score 7):

Certainly.  C# uses a C-like syntax, but I think that you will find it to be easier to learn than C.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to be repeating a lot of answers here, but I wanted to say something in a more specific way than other people have said.

I think it's just fine to jump into C# or any other object oriented language as your first language. In fact many people argue that an OO language should be your first language if you want to become good at OO because you won't be stuck in procedural thinking.

That being said, good programmers that don't have at least a decent working mental model for what is happening under the covers are few and far between. This means, eventually you should learn how a computer manages memory, pointers, how a CPU executes instructions etc... Eventually reading through a C book and an Assembly book would be a good idea IMHO. I don't think you need to become proficient at either; you just need to come to a basic understanding of how the the computer and programming languages work.

Answer (score 3):

While C is a good language to learn in general, I do not believe you will get any specific knowledge that will help you learn C#.

Answer (score 2):

My question would be are you trying to *choose a first language to learn programming?* (C# being an option) or do you know another language and think you might need to learn C before C#?

If you aren't trying to learn programming, then I would say you can skip C and go straight to C#. But for a first language, I would advise neither. Try for a scripting language that you can really writing code quickly.

Comment: have written programs in assembly and embedded c ( if... else, do, while etc types ) just out of curiosity and taking a step ahead asked this question ....

Comment: If you've done that, you've pretty well learned what C is going to teach you.  Go for the C#.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When I started with C#, I had no experience with C.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that many new programmers fail to mention is what do they want to make? Do you want to make something simple like hello world? Or are you looking to make something more complex like a GUI application or a video game?

The reason this is important is that not every programming language is appropriate for every task. As others have mentioned, C is a great systems and driver language (or really anything that requires low level interfacing or extreme performance), and C# is designed to build desktop applications ranging from text editors to huge multi-tier enterprise solutions. Despite the names of these languages, they really only share a similar name and a few pieces of syntax in common.

I would recommend starting with C# and save C for later. You can start working quickly with a lot of free tools such as [Visual Studio Express C#](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/). If later you want to start working on stuff like the Linux kernel, compilers or hardware drivers you can quickly pick up C. C is still a worthwhile language to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible.

Knowing other languages is always helpful - if only because you've been exposed to the programming way of thinking - but not essential.

Answer (score 1):

Like me if you are in a hurry to learn the new language, jump right in. But if you have a lot of time (student), i think everyone who wants to be called a coder should know C.

Comment: C?  C is for those high-level weaklings.  Everyone who wants to be called a *programmer* should know assembly!  :-P  jk

Comment: No, if you *really* want to be called a programmer, then you need to be able to program in binary :).

Comment: Assembly, binary.  Same thing.  Just different keywords :P

Comment: I take back my words as I said it without knowing the OP's background. The reason for prescribing C is to gain an understanding of inner working of the computer. I think developing in any unmanaged language helps you understand the inner working of the computer at a high level, especially if you, like me, did not have a formal education in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!  C# is a much higher level language than C, and it handles a lot of the details for you.

One recommendation though, C# is a very good language, but it comes with a slightly steeper learning curve than VB.NET.  VB.NET ***IS NOT*** Visual Basic, it just carries over some of the syntax.

VB.NET's syntax and keywords are easier to learn and can then easily be translated to C#.  Aside from special-cases there's very few things that one language can do that the other can't, and since VB.NET is easier to learn I'm a huge proponent of using it as a "welcome to .NET" language.

---

Just to clarify: you shouldn't carry the stigma's of "Classic" VB over to VB.NET, VB6 and VB.NET are entirely different languages and frameworks with only superficial resemblances.

VB.NET offers a few niceties for new developers:

- let nit-picky syntax.  C# can make a green developer pull their hair out because they forget ()'s on a void, or added them to a property.
- Visual Studio offers quick feedback on non-compilable code
- VB.NET uses words in places where C# uses symbols.  In the below examples not that C# expects you to know that ":" means either "Inherits" or "Implements" depending on the argument that follows, VB.NET says "Inherits MyBaseClass" and "Implements INamedObject", which is much more intuitive

To be fair, there is one **major** gripe I have with VB.NET's default code templates--they don't have the "Option Strict On" and "Option Explicit On" statements at the top.  If you get into VB.NET be sure to add these to every class, they'll let the compiler do more proactive error checking and result in higher quality code *and* understanding of .NET's Type system

To offer an example of equivalent .NET code written in C# and VB.NET:

C#

```
interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    void PrintType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}

class MyConcreteClass : MyBaseClass, INamedObject
{
    public MyConcreteClass()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Interface INamedObject
    Property Name() As String
End Interface

MustInherit Class MyBaseClass

    Sub PrintType()
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType.Name)
    End Sub

End Class

Class MyConcreteClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass
    Implements INamedObject

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String Implements INamedObject.Name
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: VB.NET is created to support .NET because VB syntax does not support .NET fully(or as near).

Comment: VB.NET and C# are largely the same thing, other than minor syntax issues.  That said, I would suggest C# rather than VB.Net, assuming you don't already know VB.  It's more popular and thus much easier to find useful resources and code samples.  I admit that it's usually pretty easy to convert between the two, though.  C# is often as much about using frameworks and whatnot as it is about syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't an educated OOP programmer, likely it's best to avoid C (or even C++) unless you are a big fan of self-loathing.  All of the other stated reasons are valid, but keep in mind that C# is also managed (look that up), so it's far more difficult to *get in 'trouble' with*.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem. As long as you grasp object-oriented programming, you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to all the questions of the form "Should I learn language X or Y? Should I learn Z before Y and X after Y?" etc is the same: Don't worry about such questions. Forget them. If you think learning C# is going to be more useful now (maybe there are more jobs, or maybe you want to join a project, or maybe you are just curious), then sit down and start learning.

If you are already good at one language, it does not take much time to pick up enough of another one to see if you can be productive using it. And, you cannot decide if you should expend a lot of time learning a language well without being familiar with it. Therefore, start studying C# if you feel like it.

To take this to a bit of an extreme, I think the fact that, about 30 years ago, I learned Z80 assembly even before learning BASIC has helped me immensely along the way. However, I would never recommend that you should not learn any other languages until you have mastered assembly. (By the way, all I remember is that opcode 0xc9 is `RET`).

So, do start learning C#. If you are curious, continue studying C as well, all the while remembering that even though both have curly braces, they are drastically different languages. Just like C and C++ are.

Answer (score 0):

Learning C or C++ would be more difficult, but you'd probably become a lot more accustomed to the basics, which is never a bad thing.

That being said, I'm not sure about "advisable", but it wouldn't be "wrong"...more a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

I found that learning Java for most OOP is most beneficial for learning C# as they are almost identical in libraries and syntax.

A knowledge of C or C++ only becomes useful once you begin diving deeper in C# into areas such as unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

similarities between C++ and C# ends in lexer.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well read "[The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)" by K&R because it's a quick read, and it will give you a background that may help with understanding performance going on behind the scenes in a garbage collection language.

Answer (score -1):

Sure C# is easier to understand. Of course, knowledge of C would help but if you don't know C then its better to start from a higher level language as C#.