# visual c# training

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Good Day

I'm self training myself in visual c#, I need some advice in learning it as quickly as possible, Is there a good study-guide or book that I can purchase for ms visual c#

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at these:

- [Quickest approach to learn C# programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746561/quickest-approach-to-learn-c-programming)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-c-quickly
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287927/best-way-to-learn-c
- [Start learning C# without knowing C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300951/start-learning-c-without-knowing-c)

... and lot's of other similar questions!

Answer (score 0):

[Quickest approach to learn C# programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746561/quickest-approach-to-learn-c-programming)

[Best way to learn C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287927/best-way-to-learn-c)

Answer (score 0):

[Head First C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514822/)

> Head First C# is a complete learning
>   experience for object-oriented
>   programming, C#, and the Visual Studio
>   IDE. Built for your brain, this book
>   covers Visual C# 2008, Visual Studio
>   2008, and the .NET Framework 3.5, and
>   teaches everything from language
>   fundamentals to advanced topics
>   including garbage collection,
>   extension methods, and double-buffered
>   animation. You'll also master C#'s
>   hottest and newest syntax, LINQ, for
>   querying your data in .NET
>   collections, SQL databases, and more.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to learn any language is to pick some project that you're interested in and that sounds feasible, but perhaps just outside your level of knowledge/expertise/comfort, then implement it.  This will allow you to learn while doing, and not only while doing, but while doing something you're interested in.  Being interested in what you're doing will increase your engagement and your hunger for learning more about the language so that you can implement your project.